# Reading properties that start with "something.." from properties file in groovy

Tags: groovy

In my groovy file i have, several tokens that begin with say "begins". I need to read all of them 1 by 1 and decrypt them.

```groovy
Properties props = new Properties()
File propsFile = newFile("/Users/332075795/Desktop/application.properties")
props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
println props.getProperty('begins')
```

I tried using startsWith however that does not work. Is there a way to read all the properties that begin with begins one by one. Would really appreciate your time and effort.Thanks

Comment: `Properties beingsProps = props.findAll{it.key.startsWith('begins')}`

Comment: That did it :) thanks a lot

Comment: related read:  groovy's GDK expose a grep method: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-grep-method.html